# Initiating page reload from the client

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server Side Reload Initiation on Ajax Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917709/server-side-reload-initiation-on-ajax-call)

How do i intitate a page relaod from the client after and ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.location.reload() is Javascript to refresh the page.